# How to get ref value of button in function [react]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

I have a simple buttons:

```
<button ref={btnRef1} onClick={loader} ></button>
<button ref={btnRef2} onClick={loader} ></button>
```

In function I want to get the value of clicked button:

```
const loader = (e) => {
console.log(e.target.ref); // does not work
};
```

How can I get ref value of clicked button?
Below short explain my problem:

```
Input: [button1] <-click
Output: "btnRef1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see event object via `console.log(e)`:

then analyze object to see which method will help you

```js
const loader = (e) => {
console.log(e); // does not work
};
```

Comment: if you had problem finding it , comment below